# Meteor app - Importing Client JS files not working with Flow Router - Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I'm having a difficult time importing client side javascript files with flow router. Without flow router, the imports work as expected but the second I introduce flow router the files aren't loaded properly. 
Here are what my files look like. Anybody out there ever experienced this ? You help is greatly appreciated! If you help me I will be 100% sure to mark your answer as so :)

client/main.js

```
import '../imports/startup/client'; // initialize all relevant javascript
import './main.html';
```

client/main.html

```
<head>
  <title>Welcome </title>
</head>
<template name="visitorLayout">
  <body>
    {{> Template.dynamic template=header }}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=main    }}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=footer  }}
  </body>
</template>

<template name="adminLayout">
  <body>
    {{> Template.dynamic template=main   }}
  </body>
</template>
```

imports/startup/client/index.js

```
import '../../ui/pages/landing_page/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js';
import '../../ui/pages/landing_page/jquery.easing.1.3.js';
import '../../ui/pages/landing_page/bootstrap.min.js';
import '../../ui/pages/landing_page/jquery.waypoints.min.js';
import './routes';
```

imports/startup/client/routes.js

```
import { FlowRouter  } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { BlazeLayout } from 'meteor/kadira:blaze-layout';

FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('visitorLayout', {
      header : "header",
      footer : "footer",
      main   : "index"
    })
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/admin', {
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('adminLayout', {
      main   : "admin"
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Are your files in the public folder? Also you shouldn't have to ../../ files , if they are in the public or node modules folder everything starts at root level I.e. "./lib/myfile.js"

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! None of the files are in the public dir. They are found at imports/ui/pages/landing_page/somefile.js

Comment: It's really strange because without flow router everything works perfectly. When I use it, messes up js loading :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess is that you have problem with files loading order. It seems like your `routes.js` is loaded before `main.html` therefore there is no template available to render. To fix, try one of the followings:

- Remove the line `import './main.html';` in `client/main.js`, files under `client` folder do not need imported they are loaded automatically.
- Create a new html file including the two templates you want to render (`visitorLayout` and `adminLayout`) under `import` folder or sub-folder of `import`, then import this new html file in `routes.js`. You also need to remove `body` tag inside those two templates, use `div` instead, [because `body` is a special tag in Meteor and are not treated like other tags](https://github.com/meteor/tutorials/blob/master/content/blaze/step02.md#html-files-in-meteor-define-templates)

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. Neither of these worked. Any other ideas ? I ended up using kadira:react-layout instead but still no luck with the imports.

Comment: I just tried to imitate you setup and it worked fine for me. Do you see any errors in console?